# Date sorted file selecting program

Tags: python, file, sorting, date, file-management

I want to perform some statistical computation on a bunch of files in a folder using a python script.

Until now i'm able to select the entire folder, sort the files and perform my computation.

```
def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=numericalSort):
    if infile == "log.txt":
        continue
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + infile
    log.write("~~File " + infile + " has been Opened Succesfully \n")
    with open(infile, "r") as f:
        next(f)
        #print "file has been opened" + infile
        for line in f:
```

Now what I want to do is letting the user input the initial and ending date and perform the same operations in the selected time interval.

Files are named as follow

```
countlog-2018-06-09.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `input` flag to write to the stdin. You may also want to perform input validation. Here is some code you can adapt to your requirements.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
date_regex = r'([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))'


def validate_date_input(date_type='start'):

    while True:
        start_date = input('Enter a valid {} date in format YYYY-MM-DD\n'.format(date_type))
        try:
            date = datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            print('"{}" is not in format YYYY-MM-DD. try again\n'.format(start_date))
        else:
            return date


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_date = validate_date_input(date_type='start')
    end_date = validate_date_input(date_type='end')

    file_name = 'countlog-2018-06-09.txt'

    file_re = re.search(date_regex, file_name)
    file_date = datetime.strptime(file_re.group(0), date_format)

    if start_date <= file_date <= end_date:
        print('Working on {}'.format(file_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you could generate a list of date in that date range as follows:

```
#generate all dates from date1 to date2
import datetime

date1 = '2011-05-03'
date2 = '2011-05-10'

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d')

date_ranges=[]
step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while start <= end:
    date_ranges.append(start.date())
    start += step
```

then you can use these date ranges to generate text file names

```
 text_file_names = ["countlog-"+str(the_date)+".txt" for the_date in date_ranges]
```

you can read the files now that you have thoose names, i think this is what you needed :)